# Create HTML button or any element using datatable render function takes lots of time for large data while using ajax dataSource

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

When create HTML button or call `date()` using **dataTable render function** takes lots of time for large data while using **ajax dataSource**.
I want to render only data which is display in first page of pagination irrespective of all pages data during dataTable initialization.
Here my code for 15k rows,Takes 3-4 mins:

```
'columnDefs': [{  
    "targets": [5],    
    "visible":true ,  
    render : function (data {
        return (moment(new Date(data)).isValid() ? moment(new 
        Date(data)).format('MMMM Do, YYYY @ h:mm:ss a') : ' -- ');
    }  
}]
```

Render function looping for all table rows irrespective of first page of pagination during initialization.And after that display data in page which takes 3-4 mins.

Comment: use `deferRender: true` ...

Comment: deferRender is not working..